# Pyscreenshot loop lag display

Tags: linux, python-3.x

thanks for reading.

I have a small application with a function that will take information from a configuration file. Such as **K:8** and then check if that key is down. Also it will use **P:255.255.255.0010.0010** then **split(".")** and convert to int and check if there is a pixel of RGB 255,255,255 at the location 10X 10Y.

This is on a loop and it seems to work fine, checking takes around maybe 0.2 seconds. Which is fast enough for what I need, but I do need a solution with a few checks a second. My **problem** is that doing this on a loop will cause a display lag. As though the displays are reduced to around 2 FPS. So wondering if anyone knows why this might be happening or what I can do to resolve it while still getting pixel checks that are within 0.3s?

Here's my function:

```
def conditionCheck():
    if DataHeader[0][0][:2] == "B:": #Box limits in a string, split and convert to int.
        bbox = DataHeader[0][0][2:]
        bbox = bbox.split(".")
        bboxx1 = int(bbox[0])
        bboxy1 = int(bbox[1])
        bboxx2 = int(bbox[2])
        bboxy2 = int(bbox[3])
    pixel = (pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=(bboxx1, bboxy1, bboxx2, bboxy2))).load() #Grab screen, within limits.
    cp = 0
    while cp < len(DataConditions): #cycle through config file list
        rp = 0
        conditionPass = 0
        while rp < len(DataConditions[cp]): #Cycle through list item's conditions.
            if DataConditions[cp][rp][:2] == "K:":
                if keyboard.is_pressed(DataConditions[cp][rp][2:]): #Check if key down, set pass to true
                    conditionPass = 1
                    rp += 1 #Move to check next condition.
                    print("PRESSED") #DEBUG
                    continue
                conditionPass = 0
                break
            if DataConditions[cp][rp][:2] == "P:": #pixel colour check, match = true
                pixelData = DataConditions[cp][rp][2:] #pixel data and location in one string, conv to int and split.
                pixelData = pixelData.split(".")
                pixelLocation = pixel[int(pixelData[3]), int(pixelData[4])]
                pixelData = pixelData[0], pixelData[1], pixelData[2]
                if pixelLocation == tuple(map(int, pixelData)):
                    print("PASSED PIXEL") #DEBUG
                    conditionPass = 1
                    rp += 1
                    continue
                conditionPass = 0
                break
            rp += 1
        if conditionPass == 1:
            return cp #end loop, send line of true condition (in config file)
        cp += 1
    return 0 #Return 0 if nothing found.
```

I'm running this on **Linux** and so I'm needing a solution that is cross platform/linux friendly.

Thoughts: I'm a bit of a noob so feel free to advise on other aspects.
I understand I'd get faster and smoother results doing this in C but other parts of my app would be hard to achieve in C (and my knowledge is limited) so I'm try and see if this can be achieved in Python but maybe there is just too much overhead?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some time, I think I've been able to find a solution using a different plugin, but same method. As such:

```
def conditionCheck():
    if DataHeader[0][0][:2] == "B:": #Box limits in a string, split and convert to int.
        bbox = DataHeader[0][0][2:]
        bbox = bbox.split(".")
        #bboxx1 = int(bbox[0])
        #bboxy1 = int(bbox[1])
        #bboxx2 = int(bbox[2])
        #bboxy2 = int(bbox[3])
        monitorWindow = {"top": int(bbox[0]), "left": int(bbox[1]), "width": int(bbox[2]), "height": int(bbox[3])}
    with mss.mss() as sct: #Grab screen, within limits.
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitorWindow)
        img = Image.new("RGB", sct_img.size)
        pixels = img.load()
        for x in range(sct_img.width):
            for y in range(sct_img.height):
                pixels[x, y] = sct_img.pixel(x, y)
    cp = 0
    while cp < len(DataConditions): #cycle through config file list
        rp = 0
        conditionPass = 0
        while rp < len(DataConditions[cp]): #Cycle through list item's conditions.
            if DataConditions[cp][rp][:2] == "K:":
                if keyboard.is_pressed(DataConditions[cp][rp][2:]): #Check if key down, set pass to true
                    conditionPass = 1
                    rp += 1 #Move to check next condition.
                    print("PRESSED") #DEBUG
                    continue
                conditionPass = 0
                break
            if DataConditions[cp][rp][:2] == "P:": #pixel colour check, match = true
                pixelData = DataConditions[cp][rp][2:] #pixel data and location in one string, conv to int and split.
                pixelData = pixelData.split(".")
                pixelLocation = pixels[int(pixelData[3]), int(pixelData[4])]
                pixelData = pixelData[0], pixelData[1], pixelData[2]
                if pixelLocation == tuple(map(int, pixelData)):
                    print("PASSED PIXEL") #DEBUG
                    conditionPass = 1
                    rp += 1
                    continue
                conditionPass = 0
                break
            rp += 1
        if conditionPass == 1:
            return cp #end loop, send line of true condition (in config file)
        cp += 1
    return 0 #Return 0 if nothing found.
```